# Raspberry pi and other board having issues communicating with MPICH

Tags: raspberry-pi, mpich, odroid, mpic++

I installed mpich on an Odroid n2+ and a Raspberry Pi. The Odroid n2+ is a more powerful board that I want to run the majority of my program, and I have the Raspberry Pi as a separate server in order to communicate with the program. I have installed mpich on both boards using the command `apt install mpich`. The Odroid board is running `Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS` while the raspberry pi is running `2020-08-20-raspios-buster-armhf-lite`. On both I ran the code posted at [example mpi send recieve](https://rookiehpc.github.io/mpi/docs/mpi_request/index.html)

If I run the code explicitly on the Odroid board, it works fine, if I run it on the raspberry pi I get an exit code 11. Therefore, I reinstalled mpich on both boards manually from https://www.mpich.org/static/downloads/3.3/mpich-3.3.tar.gz

When this happens, and I compile the code, it works on both boards individually. I can also run the command `mpirun -f machinefile -n 2 hostname` and it prints the hostname of each board. This tells me that I setup ssh correctly and mpich is able to login to both boards. However, when I run the code above, that sends and receives messages, it pauses when `MPI_Ssend` and `MPI_Wait(&request, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);` are called in the code.

I compiled it with the commands `mpic++ test_sendRecv.cpp -Wall -Werror -o test_sendRecv`, then ran using `mpirun -f machinefile -n 2 ./test_sendRecv`. If I use `mpiexec` instead of `mpirun` I get the same issue.

If I am correct, this means that the boards are unable to pass messages between each other?

Is there a way to remedy this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same issue with other boards. I never played around with it enough to really figure out what was causing the problem or come up with a solution. However, I did create a repository that can use sockets as a more pseudo-MPI. They only pass string messages, but I'm sure it would be pretty straight forward to add extra types, and even file passing. I put the repository [here](https://github.com/moldenha/socketMPI)